# Biblatex: 'et al.' instead of 'u.a.' for locations

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to replace the German 'u.a.' with 'et al.' for author lists in citations and locations in the bibliography. I thought this could be done all together using

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}
```

but strangely enough, the 'u.a.' persists for the locations in the bibliography. I suspect there must be some other string that has to be modified accordingly but don't know which one.

Your advice is much appreciated.

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{k1,
        Location = {Berlin and London and New York and Stockholm},
        Author = {Surname, Firstname},
        Publisher = {Publisher},
        Title = {This is the book},
        Date = {2013}
    }
    @inbook{k2,
        Author = {Surname, Firstname},
        Title = {This is the title},
        Booktitle = {And this is the booktitle},
        Editor = {Clarke Kent},
        Location = {Berlin and London and New York and Stockholm},
        Publisher = {Publisher},
        Date = {1984},
        Pages = {28-439}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    autocite=footnote,
    date=year,
    style=ext-authoryear,
    natbib=false,
    labelyear,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    nohashothers=true, 
    maxbibnames=99,
    maxcitenames=3,
    giveninits=true,
    dashed=false,
    dateuncertain=true
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
   This is a citation of a book: \cite{k1}\\
   and an inbook: \cite{k2}
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic `luainputenc` suggests you use LuaLaTeX, in which case you should definitely not load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Also `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` itself is fairly pointless since the default encoding for LuaLaTeX is UTF-8 anyway. (Since April 2018 UTF-8 is also the default in pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I recently switched from pdfLaTex to LuaLaTeX and just replaced the respective packages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string you are looking for is called `andmore`.

`andothers` is used for name lists and `andmore` for other lists like `publisher`, `location`, ... (just like `multinamedelim` and `finalnamedelim` are used for name lists and `multilistdelim` and `finallistdelim` for other lists).

(I think this is quite useful. In German I'm quite fond of "et al." for name lists, but I would never use "et al." for publishers or locations, there I'd go for "u.a.".)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  nohashothers=true, 
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=3,
  giveninits=true,  
  autocite=footnote,
  date=year,
  dateuncertain=true,
  doi=false,
  eprint=false,
  isbn=false,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
   andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
   andmore   = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{k1,
  author    = {Surname, Firstname},
  title     = {This is the book},
  date      = {2013},
  location  = {Berlin and London and New York and Stockholm},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@inbook{k2,
  author    = {Surname, Firstname},
  title     = {This is the title},
  booktitle = {And this is the booktitle},
  editor    = {Clarke Kent},
  date      = {1984},
  location  = {Berlin and London and New York and Stockholm},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  pages     = {28-439},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  This is a citation of a book: \cite{k1}
  and an inbook: \cite{k2}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Surname, F. (2013). This is the book. Berlin et al.: Publisher.]